# How to transform array into array of objects by Lodash

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, lodash

For Example,how to transform:

```
[
  "20170101|9,4,4,2,6",
  "20170102|0,7,5,6,2"
]
```

into

```
[
  { 
    date:"20170101"
    numbers:[9, 4, 4, 2, 6]
    sum:25
    oddOrEven:'odd',
  },
  { 
    date:"20170102",
    numbers:[0, 7, 5, 6, 2],
    sum:20,
    oddOrEven:'even',
  }
]
```

It's much better if use lodash without intermediate variable.

Comment: https://lodash.com/docs/#map  `_.map(myArray, parseItem);` You can write your own function to parse a line to an object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not one line, but it will give you an idea how to do it.

```js
var a =[
  "20170101|9,4,4,2,6",
  "20170102|0,7,5,6,2"
];


a = _.map(a, function(o){
   
   var split   = o.split('|'),
       numbers = _.map(split[1].split(','), _.ary(parseInt, 1)),
       sum     = _.sum(numbers);

   return {
      date: split[0],
      numbers: numbers,
      sum: sum,
      oddOrEven: (sum % 2 == 0 ? 'even' : 'odd')
   }

});

console.log(a);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/lodash/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```js
var aryData = [ "20170101|9,4,4,2,6", "20170102|0,7,5,6,2"]
   ,aryObjects = [];
for( var i in aryData ) {
    var aryFields = aryData[i].split("|");

    if ( aryFields.length != 2 ) {
        continue;
    }
    var aryNumbers = aryFields[1].split(","), intSum = 0;

    for( var n in aryNumbers ) {
        aryNumbers[n] = parseInt(aryNumbers[n]);
        intSum += aryNumbers[n];
    }
    aryObjects.push({date:aryFields[0]
                 ,numbers:aryNumbers
                     ,sum:intSum
               ,oddorEven:(((intSum % 2) == 0) ? "even" : "odd")});
}
console.dir(aryObjects);
```